# Azure Active Directory Authentication Fails in Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure, powerapps

I am trying to authenticate for my dynamic crm api in flutter app. I am using aad_auth package. But I can't authenticate. I created application in aad, followed all necessary steps. Still there is authentication errors. Here are my screenshots:

AAD App:

[image]

Flutter Conf:

[image]

login action and error:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: have you gone through this aad_oauth document. https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth

Comment: Also as per the error screenshot I can see that https://i.imgur.com/uvQpuib.png there is some code error **AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(c)** check that as well

Comment: what is wrong? Code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth package for it.

And sign in to the firebase using the Microsoft Auth provider.

```
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(
  "microsoft.com", ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'your-tenent-id'});
```

This integrates nicely with firebase so, firebase authStateChange also works with this method.